# Firebase intraday-events in Data Studio from BigQuery

Tags: android, ios, firebase, google-bigquery, looker-studio

We have an iOS-app and an Android-app where Firebase-events are sent to Google BigQuery and displayed in Google Data Studio.

For both clients we have a datasource for app_events_intraday_YYYYMMDD. The problem is that when each day passes, we have to remove the datasource for intraday events and re-add them. I guess it has something todo with the datasource rolling each night where they get a new suffix for each day.

Is there any way to add the datasource for intraday events without having to re-add them every midnight?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create [a view](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/views#creating_a_view) from these tables, and use [wildcard-tables](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-wildcard-tables) to address the tables

```
bq mk --use_legacy_sql=false \
    --view 'SELECT user_dim.user_id, ..., event_dim.date, ... FROM `PROJECT_ID.DATASET.app_events_intraday_*`' \
    [PROJECT_ID].[DATASET].[VIEW]
```

And use [this view in Data Studio report](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/visualize-data-studio#create_a_chart_using_a_custom_query)

Comment: I get an error when running this: Error: Syntax error: Expected keyword FROM but got "." at [1:26]

Comment: The query mentioned in the answer is not complete, `...` should be replaced with the rest of the fields you care about in your tables, more details on the schema of exported tables https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7029846?hl=en&ref_topic=7029512

Comment: If you update the post with the desired schema, I can update the query